# ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure

Tags: jenkins, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Jenkins runs in Linux vm without GUI
testcafe@1.9.4
testcafe-reporter-xunit@2.1.0
chromium@3.0.2
node -v
v14.2.0

**Execute Shell:**
npm install chromium
npm install firefox

npm install testcafe testcafe-reporter-xunit

node_modules/.bin/testcafe "firefox:node_modules/firefox:headless" tests/smokeTest.js -r xunit:res.xml

node_modules/.bin/testcafe "chromium:node_modules/chromium/lib/chromium/chrome-linux/chrome --headless --no-sandbox" tests/smokeTest.js -r xunit:res.xml

**Jenkins Job:**
ERROR Unable to establish one or more of the specified browser connections. This can be caused by network issues or remote device failure.

Type "testcafe -h" for help.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: The firefox package is a reference to the node-firefox package intended for interacting with Firefox via the DevTools Remote Protocol. It doesn't contain firefox executables. If you don't need to install firefox into the jenkins workspace locally, you can install it using the system package manager, e.g., `sugo apt install firefox` and run testcafe with the 'firefox:headless' browser alias

Comment: firefox just is for example, and why the same issue with chromium?

Answer (score 3):

Before running tests on a specific browser, it is necessary either to install it into the system, e.g. `sudo app install firefox` or install a portable browser, e.g. `npm install chromium`.

In the latter case, you need to ensure that the installation is correct, i.e. the browser's executable exists and all required dependencies are installed. You can use the following command to check the executable's dependencies: `ldd node_modules/chromium/lib/chromium/chrome-linux/chrome`. Note that if you install the browser into the system with the system package manager, it will install all required dependencies automatically.

Comment: Thank you! I will check